# Join tables and return total number of matches for each record

Tags: mysql

I have the following two tables:

Actions:

```
id | action
---|--------
 1 | Some action
 2 | Another action
 3 | And another
```

and CompletedActions:

```
id | userid | actionid
---|--------|---------
 1 | 4      | 1
 2 | 4      | 2
 3 | 4      | 2
 4 | 4      | 2
 5 | 5      | 1
```

And want to join them on a given userid and then return all actions and how many times a user has completed an action returning a table as follows using userid=4 as an example:

```
id | action         | times
---|----------------|-------
 1 | Some action    | 1
 2 | Another Action | 3
 3 | And Another    | 0
```

Is this possible in MySQL?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  If so, please edit your question with your attempt.

Comment: In your example, shouldn't the "times" value for action id=2 be 3 instead of 4?

Comment: Absolutely, corrected now thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic `join`/aggregation query, with a slight twist:

```
select a.id, a.action, count(ca.userid) as times
from Actions a left outer join
     CompletedActions ca 
     on ca.actionid = a.id and
        ca.userid = 4
group by a.actionid;
```

The slight twist is the use of `left outer join` to be sure that all actions are included in the result.

By the way, you can also write this using correlated subqueries:

```
select a.*,
       (select count(*)
        from CompletedActions ca
        where ca.actionid = a.id and
              ca.userid = 4
       ) as times
from actions a;
```

Under some circumstances, this can have better performance.